# Passing data to a MaterialUI drawer from a mapped array

Tags: reactjs

I've been messing around with React for a few weeks now. And I'm at that point where I need to be more efficient and flexible on how I represent data. I have a simply array like this one:

```
const projects = [
    {
        name: 'Google',
        type: 'Browser',
        img: '/img/projects/new/google.jpg',
        url:'http://google.com/',
    },
    {
        name: 'Windows',
        type: 'OS',
        img: '/img/projects/new/windows.jpg',
        url:'http://microsoft.com/',
    },
    {
        name: 'Apple',
        type: 'Computer',
        img: '/img/projects/new/apple.jpg',
        url:'http://apple.com/',
    },
];
```

and my class for my component (simplified):

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            openDrawer: false,
        }
    }

    handleDrawerOpen = () => { this.setState({ openDrawer: true }); };
    handleDrawerClose = () => { this.setState({ openDrawer: false }); };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    projects.map((project, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <img src={project.img} alt={project.name} />
                            <h6>{project.name}</h6>
                            <p>{project.type}</p>
                            <a target="_blank" href={project.url}> <WebIcon/> </a>
                            <a onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}> <LinkIcon/> </a>
                            <LSDrawer
                                open={this.state.openDrawer}
                                clickClose={this.handleDrawerClose}
                                title={project.name}
                                anchor='top'
                                rightButtons={
                                    <Fab
                                        color="secondary"
                                        size="small"
                                        aria-label="Close"
                                        onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                                        <CloseIcon />
                                    </Fab>
                                }>
                                Some info will go in here
                            </LSDrawer>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default (Home);
```

This is the [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/841848x9q9) where you can play around with it if you'd like

Now, here's what I want to learn. How can I pass to the drawer only the item being clicked on? So that if I click on the Windows item, the drawer shows "Windows" in the title, if I click on "Google", I'd see "Google" as the drawer title, and so on. Once I learn this, I can expand from there and pass the image to the Drawer body and everything else. Essentially apply the same concept to modal windows, etc.

I'm looking for something practical. Something you'd most likely see in the professional world (nevermind splitting the component into re-usable components, that part I can do, in fact, the LSDrawer is a re-usable component)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have one drawer change content dynamically you'd need to remove the Drawer from your map function, and save a reference to the clicked object in your state somewhere to feed the proper data to the Drawer component.

Not clear if this is exemplary code but you could alter your open handler and bind it to the icon like so:

```
handleDrawerOpen = (index) => {
    this.setState({ openDrawer: true, currentIndex: index });
  };

...

<a onClick={() => this.handleDrawerOpen(i)}>
```

And move your Drawer outside the map call to give it the title you want based on the saved index:

```
        <LSDrawer
          open={this.state.openDrawer}
          clickClose={this.handleDrawerClose}
          title={this.state.projects[this.state.currentIndex].name}
          anchor="top"
          rightButtons={
            <Fab
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              aria-label="Close"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </Fab>
          }
        >
          Some info will go in here
            </LSDrawer>
```

Note I also saved the projects variable to the state, since data storage is its prime function.

Fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0yy4rq8l8v).

Comment: Nice and clear! Great job and many thanks. I understand the concept here and I should be able to implement further...At least until I get to Redux and start messing with more heavy data handling. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers